# Web Development, putting python in the browser

Tags: python, html, web-development, web

I want to write a web page that allows the user to upload a set of python files and then it shows the file contents based on the selected file and allows the user to then run the file and see the output/interact with any prompts.

I am looking for recommendations on language, libraries and/or frameworks to consider for this project. It will only be used by my programming professor for now so it doesn't have to be perfect, I'm just trying to save him from opening and running each file separately for his intro course.

[image: This is an idea of what I'm wanting to create.]

Comment: I came across this, but I haven't tried it yet.  It's not exactly what you want, but it might be helpful to you: https://github.com/bitagoras/PyPadPlusPlus

Comment: There's a ton of different frameworks you could use. Tkinter might work, since it's written for python and you can just use `exec` or `import` to run the code.

Comment: Thanks pizza! I didnt know Tkinter had that so I'll look at using that!